# jQuery : toggle footer, resize from #px to 100% width and back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, footer

I'm working on a toggle footer, it is `width:100%;`.

I set it to have `max-width:670px`, and I want it to expand to 100% width before the toggle animation.
Here is my codepen:
http://codepen.io/GCW/pen/ZYbvPO

As you can see, it works. But I had to set `maxWidth: '5000'` to have it full width in mostly every kind of screen. In this way, my animation is not fluid, my footer goes back to 670px very fast. I played with animation time, but I'm sure there is a better way to do that.
I guess that my code is too long for this simple action, too.

I also tried with `var window_width = $(window).width()` and then `.animate({
    maxWidth: window_width }..` and it works well, just until I resize my window because it has a precise width value, and not a percentage, so it has some fixed width.

Comment: So whats the exact issue? Your animation is not fluid because the huge gap of 5000 and 670? Is that correct?

Comment: Right. I'm looking for a way to get a 100% width without that crazy 5000 value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the css 100vw property for new browsers but for older browsers you can use jquery to get the window width. Here is your code with my adjustment below below.

```
 (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.nav-toggle').click(function(){

            var content_selector = $(this).attr('href');
            var my_switch = $(this); 

            //Added variable
            var viewPortWidth = $(window).outerWidth();

            if (my_switch.hasClass('close_toggle')) {
                    $(content_selector).slideToggle(function(){
                        $('.collapsing_footer').animate({
                        maxWidth: '670'}, 400);
                        my_switch.removeClass('close_toggle');
                    });   

                    //Remove resize event bind 
                    jQuery(window).unbind();

            } else { 


                //on resize adjust the max width
                jQuery(window).resize(function () {
                    //reset viewport width variable to current
                    viewPortWidth = $(window).outerWidth();
                     $('.collapsing_footer').css({ maxWidth : viewPortWidth });
                  console.log("here");
                });


                $('.collapsing_footer').animate({ maxWidth: viewPortWidth }, 600, 

                function() {
                    $(content_selector).slideToggle(
                        function(){
                         my_switch.toggleClass('close_toggle');
                        }
                    );

                    $('body').animate({ scrollTop: 999999 }, 700);

                });

            }

        });

    }); 
    })(jQuery);
```

If you have browser version detection i suggest you use that to fill the variable viewPortWidth. Here is an article about vw css and also contains browser support. http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: right, but if you toggle the menu when you are on 1000px width for example, then you resize the browser to 1500px, the menu remains on 1000px because of the stored value of the viewPortWidth

Comment: That's correct, ill adjust to make up for browser re sizing.

Comment: I added a window re size event, it now adjusts the max with when the browser adjusts its size. It also clears that event when the menu is not open to prevent the 670 max with from changing.

Comment: Sorry again. It was perfct (and thanks for your explaination) until I had to use it with my fixed top menu. Look at this:
http://codepen.io/GCW/pen/ogjqqj
The `jQuery(window).unbind();` prevent my header to hide when the scroll comes back to the top

Comment: You can use name spaces and change up your code a bit. Take a look at this. http://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/ your going to want to to jQuery(window).on('resize.MyWindow', function() {}); then instead of unbind you do jQuery(window).off('resize.MyWindow'); That SHOULD solve it.

Comment: Also I notice that `$('body').animate({ scrollTop: 999999 }, 700);` doesn't work on IE. Everything is ok with `$('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: ...`

Answer (score 1):

You could try using viewport width:

```
maxWidth: '100vw'
```